# Developer Enrollment Paying Issue

Tags: ios, applications, developer-program

Today i made a payment of 99$ to get some certificate for developement but now apple just sent me a email saying:

`The billing information you used on the Apple Online Store to purchase an Apple Developer Program membership does not match the billing information you provided during enrollment. Before your membership can be activated, we'll need a copy of your government-issued photo ID.`

So i did the payment with my father Debit Card and i was wondering if is it gonna be okay if i send my passport photo, contact them, send them some papers saying that my father was conscious of this payment or should i send them something else?.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple's Development Program Payment](https://developer.apple.com/support/purchase-activation/) page:

> ### Payment
>
> You can choose from the payment methods presented during your membership purchase. If you are paying by credit card and enrolling as an individual, **you must use your own credit card to complete your purchase. If you do not, your enrollment will be delayed and you will be asked for a copy of your government-issued photo identification**. After you’ve completed your purchase, you will receive an order acknowledgement email from Apple Online Store and a confirmation email from Apple Developer Relations.

Apple puts all relevant info for the developer program online and it's fairly easy to search and find the answers.  Go to the page I linked-to if you have more questions.  You can also contact Apple directly.

Comment: Hey just a question Now should we have to send 'government-issued photo identification' of Credit card holder ?

Comment: @nikhil I do to think so. If your the card holder and you're using your own card, you shouldn't need to send a copy of your ID.

Comment: @fsb_ thanks for your help. I am not using my own card.So i sent card holder's Aadhar card to Verify but apple sent me a email saying "Upon review of your Passport, we found that the name does not match" they wanted My Aadhar card and got verified.

Comment: I've never done that so I don't know Apple's rules about it.  You might want to contact Apple directly because your situation is a bit unique.